# How to get all NFTs from an Enumerable ERC721 Smart Contract?

Tags: erc-721, nft, arrays, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm trying to add a function to the ERC721 Smart Contract to return all the NFTs (items identified by tokenID) from a user address.

At first, I was thinking on something like the following:

```
    mapping (address => uint256[]) private nftListByAddress;

function getNFTsByAddress(address user)public view returns( uint256 [] memory){
    return nftListByAddress[user];
}
```

...but managing arrays in Solidity is a bit cumbersome, and can lead to bugs and excessive gas spending when iterating to delete and reorder the arrays (when a NFT transfer between addresses happens).

I have found the [OpenZeppelin's ERC721Enumerable in their docs](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721Enumerable), which states:

> This implements an optional extension of ERC721 (...) that adds
> **enumerability** of (...) **all token ids owned by each account**.

It sounded great to me at first, but I did not see any function like:

```
getNFTsByAddress(address user) --> Array
```

So, digging [into the code implementation on Github](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.0/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) I discovered that this Smart Contract's implementation does not return any array. The only function that could help is the following:

```
function tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address owner, uint256 index) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        require(index < ERC721.balanceOf(owner), "ERC721Enumerable: owner index out of bounds");
        return _ownedTokens[owner][index];
    }
```

My current approach, to avoid using arrays, is to use Enumberable ERC721 with the following approach in the server side:

**1- Get the total amount of NFTs from an address:**

```
ERC721.balanceOf(owner)
```

**2- Iterate from 0 to total amount number**, calling to:

```
 tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, current-loop-index)
```

Is this the best approach to get what I'm trying (giving one owner address --> get all NFTs of ERC721 Smart Contract)?

Thanks

Comment: I think it is the only good approach :)

Comment: This is the only good approach and the one desxcribed by opzenzeppelin: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Enumerable-tokenOfOwnerByIndex-address-uint256- ("Use along with balanceOf to enumerate all of owner's tokens.")

Comment: @DrGorilla.eth what do you think about this option (the same but inside the Smart Contract)?: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115216/issues-looping-arrays-inside-view-functions-in-solidity