# Issues looping arrays inside view functions, in Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

[I asked this question recently](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114872/how-to-get-all-nfts-from-an-enumerable-erc721-smart-contract?noredirect=1#comment137939_114872) about discovering the list of NFTs from an owner's address.

My first approach, to avoid using arrays, was to use [Enumberable ERC721](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.4.0/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) with the following approach in the server side:

1- Get the **total amount of NFTs** from an address:

```
ERC721.balanceOf(owner)
```

2- **Iterate** from 0 to total amount number, calling to:

```
 tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, current-loop-index)
```

**NEW approach: View function (looping arrays in Solidity)**

**...BUT** as far as I'm concerned the problem with arrays and out of gas issues are only when transactions are involved. My approach is a read only function, doing the same as mentioned above but in a **Solidity view function**. Is there any problem with this approach?

```
  function tokensOfOwner(address owner) public view returns (uint256[] memory) {
        
        uint256[] memory itemList;
        for (uint256 i=0; i <= ERC721.balanceOf(owner); i++){
            itemList[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, i);
        }
        return itemList;
    }
```

Comment: I was writing a comment about the `require` statement when you edited your post, following the same idea, you could remove the `index` parameters as it is unused (and was already useless with the `require` statement) no ?

Comment: Yes sure, it was a quick modification of the original function. I removed the index parameter and the require.

Comment: Just change `uint256[] memory itemList;` to `uint256[] memory itemList = new uint256[](length);` as you cannot use dynamic arrays outside of storage, and even if you could there is no point you already know the size upfront. With `uint256 length = ERC721.balanceOf(owner);`. You can also replace the existing call to `balanceOf()` in the for loop by `length`.

Comment: I made the modification you proposed but I'm getting: MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. {code: -32603, message: 'Internal JSON-RPC error.'

Comment: I also tried: `uint256 size = ERC721.balanceOf(owner); uint256[size] memory itemList; with no luck`

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't mention that `i <= ERC721.balanceOf(owner);` is incorrect. If `i` == `array.length` then `i` is an out of range index. As indexes start at 0 , the maximum is `array.length - 1`, just do as I showed you in the previous comment, and change the condition in for for loop to `uint256 i=0; i < ERC721.balanceOf(owner); i++` and that should do it. My bad for not mentioning that.